# How to make array key unique all over array

Tags: php, arrays, unique

How to make an array key unique? 
i tried `array_unique` but it throws:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Array to string conversion

Filename: models/mdashboard.php

Line Number: 115
```

Here is the array:

```
Array
(
    [100053] => 100053
    [100072] => 100072
    [100054] => 100054
    [100055] => Array
        (
        [100056] => Array
            (
                [100057] => 100057
                [100058] => 100058
                [100059] => 100059
                [100060] => 100060
                [100071] => 100071
            )

        [100061] => Array
            (
                [100063] => 100063
                [100062] => Array
                    (
                        [100065] => 100065
                        [100066] => Array
                            (
                                [100067] => 100067
                                [100068] => 100068
                                [100069] => 100069
                                [100070] => 100070
                            )

                        [100064] => 100064
                    )

            )

    )

    [100056] => Array
    (
        [100057] => 100057
        [100058] => 100058
        [100059] => 100059
        [100060] => 100060
        [100071] => 100071
    )

    [100061] => Array
    (
        [100063] => 100063
        [100062] => Array
            (
                [100065] => 100065
                [100066] => Array
                    (
                        [100067] => 100067
                        [100068] => 100068
                        [100069] => 100069
                        [100070] => 100070
                    )

                [100064] => 100064
            )

    )

    [100062] => Array
    (
        [100065] => 100065
        [100066] => Array
            (
                [100067] => 100067
                [100068] => 100068
                [100069] => 100069
                [100070] => 100070
            )

        [100064] => 100064
    )

    [100066] => Array
    (
        [100067] => 100067
        [100068] => 100068
        [100069] => 100069
        [100070] => 100070
    )

)
```

Comment: You should share `mdashboard.php` file's related part here to see what caused error.

Comment: its having so much irrelevant line of code that not related

Comment: i want to make all the key at any level must unique ...  suppose key 100061 is exists in 100056 so its should not be present in array further

Comment: If you want unique key distributed among multiple levels you should use 2 arrays. An additional array for indexing the keys of your original multilevel array. The indexing array can store boolean values or a reference to the data (as you wish).

Comment: thanks you ! i compare it with raw array